# How to store list data into the database using django?

Tags: python, django, database, list

> I have django model with one field calle tag_name and with the forms i
>   am taking input from the user like below:

[image]

> Now in the views.py i got the input from the user whatever he passed
>   and i have splited into the list like this:

```
def function_name(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TagsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # form = form.save(commit=False)
        tag_name = form.data['tag_name']
        split_tags = tag_name.split()
        # print(split_tags)
        form.save()
        return redirect('index_questions')
else:
    form = TagsForm()

context = {'form': form, }
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

> with this i am storing data in to the table like this:

[image]

> but i want to add these 2 name in to the table as seperated rows something like this:

what can i do in the views.py file or in to the model to make this happen?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to iterate over the tags and create an object for each

```
tags = tag_name.split()
for tag in tags:
    Tag.objects.create(tag_name=tag)
```

[`formsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) can provide a nice solution to editing/creating multiple of the same model

Comment: Thank you, thats is what i was looking for.